# Restructuring Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been suggested to move from the class structure, defining my own class, to the pandas DataFrame realm as I envision to have many operations with my data.

At this point I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   ID   Name    Recording   Direction   Duration    Distance    Path Raw
    0   129 Houston Woodlands   X   12.3    8   HWX.txt
    1   129 Houston Woodlands   Y   12.3    8   HWY.txt
    2   129 Houston Woodlands   Z   12.3    8   HWZ.txt
    3   129 Houston Downtown    X   11.8    10  HDX.txt
    4   129 Houston Downtown    Y   11.8    10  HDY.txt
    5   129 Houston Downtown    Z   11.8    10  HDZ.txt
    ... ... ... ..  ..  ... ... ...
    2998    333 Chicago Downtown    X   3.4 50  CDX.txt
    2999    333 Chicago Downtown    Y   3.4 50  CDY.txt
    3000    333 Chicago Downtown    Z   3.4 50  CDZ.txt
```

This is ok at the time, however, I would like to group all the X Y Z after loading the files/arrays (add columns) and, in addition to that, add new column with products of the array manipulation (e.g. FFT).

Finally I would like a DataFrame that would look like this:

```
    ID  Name    Recording   Duration    Distance    Rawx    Rawy    Raxz    FFT-Rawx    FFT-Rawy    FFT-Raxz
0   129 Houston Woodlands   12.3    8   HWX.txt HWY.txt HWZ.txt FFT-HWX.txt FFT-HWY.txt FFT-HWZ.txt
1   129 Houston Downtown    11.8    10  HDX.txt HDY.txt HDZ.txt FFT-HDX.txt FFT-HDY.txt FFT-HDZ.txt
... ... ... ..  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1000    333 Chicago Downtown    3.4 50  CDX.txt CDY.txt CDZ.txt FFT-CDX.txt FFT-CDY.txt FFT-CDZ.txt
```

Any idea how?

Unfortunately, not all my cells have this nice structure.

Instead of

HDX HDY HDZ

I can have "random names". However, I know that they are in this order:

First is Z, second is Y, and third is X always. Each record has those three signals and then the next record comes.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
k =1
for row in df:
    if k % 3 == 0:
    # Do something
    elif k % 3 == 2:
    # Do something
    else:
    # Do something
    k += 1
```

However, I don't know if there is an option to add an empty column to an already existing dataframe and fill it through a loop. If there is such an option, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider concatenating a list of [pandas.pivot_tables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). However, prior to concatenating, the dataframe must be sliced by the *Raw* value common stems --*HW.txt*, *HD.txt*, *CD.txt*-- grouped using regex:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
ID,Name,Recording,Direction,Duration,Distance,Path,Raw
0,129,Houston,Woodlands,X,12.3,8,HWX.txt
1,129,Houston,Woodlands,Y,12.3,8,HWY.txt
2,129,Houston,Woodlands,Z,12.3,8,HWZ.txt
3,129,Houston,Downtown,X,11.8,10,HDX.txt
4,129,Houston,Downtown,Y,11.8,10,HDY.txt
5,129,Houston,Downtown,Z,11.8,10,HDZ.txt
6,333,Chicago,Downtown,X,3.4,50,CDX.txt
7,333,Chicago,Downtown,Y,3.4,50,CDY.txt
8,333,Chicago,Downtown,Z,3.4,50,CDZ.txt'''))

# UNIQUE 'RAW' STEM GROUPINGS
grp = set([re.sub(r'X|Y|Z', '', i) for i in df['Raw'].tolist()])

dfList = []
for i in grp:    
    # FILTER FOR 'RAW' VALUES THAT CONTAIN STEMS 
    temp = df[df['Raw'].isin([i.replace('.txt', txt+'.txt') for txt in ['X','Y','Z']])]    
    # RUN PIVOT (LONG TO WIDE)
    temp = temp.pivot_table(values='Raw', 
                            index=['Name', 'Recording', 'Direction','Distance', 'Path'],
                            columns=['Duration'], aggfunc='min')
    dfList.append(temp)

# CONCATENATE (STACK) DFS IN LIST 
finaldf = pd.concat(dfList).reset_index()

# RENAME AND CREATE FFT COLUMNS
finaldf = finaldf.rename(columns={'X': 'Rawx', 'Y': 'Rawy', 'Z': 'Rawz'})
finaldf[['FFT-Rawx', 'FFT-Rawy', 'FFT-Rawz']] = 'FFT-' + finaldf[['Rawx', 'Rawy', 'Rawz']]
```

**Output**

```
# Duration  Name Recording  Direction  Distance  Path     Rawx     Rawy     Rawz     FFT-Rawx     FFT-Rawy     FFT-Rawz
# 0          129   Houston   Downtown      11.8    10  HDX.txt  HDY.txt  HDZ.txt  FFT-HDX.txt  FFT-HDY.txt  FFT-HDZ.txt
# 1          129   Houston  Woodlands      12.3     8  HWX.txt  HWY.txt  HWZ.txt  FFT-HWX.txt  FFT-HWY.txt  FFT-HWZ.txt
# 2          333   Chicago   Downtown       3.4    50  CDX.txt  CDY.txt  CDZ.txt  FFT-CDX.txt  FFT-CDY.txt  FFT-CDZ.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a partial answer! I got a little confused about what you wanted with regard to the FFT (fast fourier transform?) and where the data were coming from.

HOWEVER, I got everything else.

First, I'm gonna make some sample data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "Name":[129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129], 
         "Recording":['Houston Woodlands', 'Houston Woodlands', 'Houston Woodlands', 
                     'Houston Downtown', 'Houston Downtown', 'Houston Downtown'], 
         "Direction": ["X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"], "Duration":[12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 11.8, 11.8, 11.8], 
         "Path_Raw":["HWX.txt", "HWY.txt", "HWZ.txt", 'HDX.txt', 'HDY.txt', 'HDZ.txt'], 
         "Distance": [8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10]})
```

NOW I'll define some new functions. I've split these apart, so they'll be a little easier to customize. Basically, I'm calling .unique and saving each Path Raw as a new variable.

```
def splitunique0(group):
    ulist = group.unique()
    return(ulist[0])


def splitunique1(group):
    ulist = group.unique()
    return(ulist[1])


def splitunique2(group):
    ulist = group.unique()
    return(ulist[2])


dothis = {"Duration":"first", "Distance":"first", 'Path_Raw': {'Rawx': splitunique0, 
                                                           'Rawy': splitunique1, 
                                                          'Raxz': splitunique2}}

new = df.groupby(["Name", "Recording"]).agg(dothis)

new.columns = ["Duration", "Distance", "Raxz", "Rawx", "Rawy"]
```

Here's the finished dataframe!

                        `Duration Distance Raxz  Rawx    Rawy
Name    Recording

129     Houston Downtown    11.8    10  HDZ.txt HDX.txt HDY.txt
        Houston Woodlands   12.3    8   HWZ.txt HWX.txt HWY.txt`